# Replace each instance of a character in variable names across multiple files

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a list of template files that contain variables in this format:

```
{{my.var}}
{{my.other.var}}
```

I need to locate each instance and replace the `.` with `_` so that each variable becomes:

```
{{my_var}}
{{my_other_var}}
```

I have tried doing this with sed and regex, but I am having trouble dealing with the fact that the variables can have any number of periods.

This is what I have so far:

```
for f in `cat list-of-files.txt`; do
    sed -i .bak -E 's/{{(.*)\.(.*)}}/{{\1_\2}}/g' ${f}
done;
```

Which results in

```
{{my_var}}
{{my.other_var}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
echo "{{ my.other.var }}" | sed -n '/{{.*}}/{s/\./-/gp}'
```

result:

```
{{ my-other-var }}
```

Pattern match for the format first and then execute the required sed commands if that pattern is met i.e. substitute - for .

Comment: Thanks! Additional note - this gave an error with the default version of sed on Mac OSX. I had to hop in to a Linux vm to use it.

Comment: The solution on Mac is to "brew install gnu-sed" and run the command with gsed instead of sed.

Comment: `echo "{{ my.other.var }} This will not work. It picks up false positives." | sed -n '/{{.*}}/{s/\./-/gp}'`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to accomplish what I wanted with PERL as well. The trick was to use lazy modifiers.

```
perl -pi.back -e 's|\{\{(\w+?)\.(\w+?)}}|{{\1_\2}}|g' <filename>
```

{{my.var}} becomes {{my_var}}